# golang: Как исправить import lookup disabled by -mod=vendor?

Tags: golang, mock, mocking

взял за пример вот это https://github.com/golang/mock/tree/main/sample .
Если клонировать этот репозиторий, все работает

скопировал файл https://github.com/golang/mock/blob/main/sample/user.go в свой репозиторий

вызываю генерацию:

```
//go:generate mockgen -destination mock_user_test.go -package user_test github.com/golang/mock/sample Index,Embed,Embedded
```

выдает

```
prog.go:12:2: cannot find module providing package github.com/golang/mock/mockge
n/model: import lookup disabled by -mod=vendor
        (Go version in go.mod is at least 1.14 and vendor directory exists.)
prog.go:12:2: cannot find module providing package github.com/golang/mock/mockge
n/model: import lookup disabled by -mod=vendor
        (Go version in go.mod is at least 1.14 and vendor directory exists.)
prog.go:12:2: no required module provides package github.com/golang/mock/mockgen
/model: go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent directory; see
'go help modules'
prog.go:14:2: no required module provides package github.com/golang/mock/sample:
 go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent directory; see 'go hel
p modules'
2023/11/02 00:42:06 Loading input failed: exit status 1
user.go:4: running "mockgen": exit status 1
```

Если прописать аналогичную строку, ошибка таже.

go env

```
set GO111MODULE=on
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOBIN=
set GOCACHE=C:\Users\G\AppData\Local\go-build
set GOENV=C:\Users\G\AppData\Roaming\go\env
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOEXPERIMENT=
set GOFLAGS=
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOINSECURE=
set GOMODCACHE=C:\Users\G\go\pkg\mod
set GONOPROXY=
set GONOSUMDB=
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=C:\Users\G\go
set GOPRIVATE=
set GOPROXY=https://proxy.golang.org,direct
set GOROOT=C:/Users/G/sdk/go1.21.3
set GOSUMDB=sum.golang.org
set GOTMPDIR=
set GOTOOLCHAIN=auto
set GOTOOLDIR=C:\Users\G\sdk\go1.21.3\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
set GOVCS=
set GOVERSION=go1.21.3
set GCCGO=gccgo
set GOAMD64=v1
set AR=ar
set CC=gcc
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=0
set GOMOD=C:\Users\G\GolandProjects\cc\cc-profile\go.mod
set GOWORK=
set CGO_CFLAGS=-O2 -g
set CGO_CPPFLAGS=
set CGO_CXXFLAGS=-O2 -g
set CGO_FFLAGS=-O2 -g
set CGO_LDFLAGS=-O2 -g
set PKG_CONFIG=pkg-config
set GOGCCFLAGS=-m64 -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -Wl,--no-gc-sections -fmessage-length=0 -ffile-prefix-map=C:\Users\G\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build2910196759=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches
```

Не понимаю как исправить.

Делал:

1. go clean -modcache
2. Удалял папку vendor из проекта.
3. go mod tidy
4. go clean -modcache

Не помогло

Не понимаю как исправить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас есть папка `vendor`. По старому соглашению, ещё от первых версий Го, предполагается, что все зависимости находятся в этой папке. Вам нужно либо удалить vendor и скачать зависимости через `go mod tidy`, либо загрузить все дополнительные зависимости в `vendor`.

Разумеется, по нынешним временам приемлемым считается вариант *удалить vendor*. Использовать `vendor` нынче не кошерно.

Comment: иными словами rm -rf vendor && go mod tidy. Все равно выдает  ``` C:\Users\G\sdk\go1.21.3\bin\go.exe generate C:\Users\G\GolandProjects\cc\cc-profile\internal\application\service\profileService.go
prog.go:14:2: no required module provides package github.com/3110Y/profile/inter
nal/applicaton/service; to add it:
        go get github.com/3110Y/profile/internal/applicaton/service
prog.go:14:2: no required module provides package github.com/3110Y/profile/inter
nal/applicaton/service: go.mod file not found in current directory or any parent
 directory; see 'go help modules'```

Comment: Где почитать про то, что использовать vendor нынче не кошерно?

Comment: и соответственно  go get github.com/3110Y/profile/internal/applicaton/service module github.com/3110Y/profile/internal/applicaton/service: git ls-remote -q origin in C:\Users\Gaevo\go\pkg\mod\cache\vcs\c5e46fa31f913d3a4d983caec14c771cb34e334d706c30f9c68f04cebb28a357: exit status 128

Comment: Я наоборот считал, что go mod vendor - это более новый подход. Что это и есть система модулей.

Comment: Ну вот, ошибка поменялась. Теперь не находится пакет. Скопируйте перечень пакетов из go.mod модуля, откуда вы взяли файл, и вставьте к себе. go mod tidy сам удалит ненужное

Comment: @Роман Я сейчас внимательнее посмотрел на ошибку: `github.com/3110Y/profile` - это ваш репозиторий? А вы в корне вашего проекта выполнили команду `go mod init github.com/3110Y/profile`, чтобы инциализировать модуль?

Comment: @Роман что же касается некошерности, то в [документации](https://go.dev/ref/mod#vendoring) прямо сказано: *Vendoring may be used to allow **interoperation with older versions of Go**, or to ensure that all files used for a build are stored in a single file tree.* Плюс собственный опыт. Когда я начинал пять лет назад, `vendor` и `make dep` встречались сплошь и рядом. В последнее время не припомню модули, в которых бы встречались `vendor`.

Comment: Спасибо большое за подробные объяснения)